# Get Xpath for href from a tag based on span tag value

Tags: html, xpath, jmeter

I am a beginner to xpath and I am unable to get XPath to get link from 'a' tag for below HTML code.

Get HREF value where span class value is "Upholstered" as shown in the snapshot.

Here, I want this value "/furniture/Bedrooms/Queen-Beds/_/N-8ddZ1z141u9?qf=styles_Upholstered" using Xpath.

[image]

Can you help me out please

Comment: Post a [mcve] as code, never as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description the relevant XPath query to `Get href value where span class value is "Upholstered` will be something like:

```
//a[@class='Upholstered']/@href
```

However you forgot to add your actual HTML code (at least partial) so the above answer might not be 100% accurate.

Reference material:

- [XPath Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)
- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath to extract the URL of your `<a>` tag

```
//ul[@class='facetOptions']/li/a[@role='checkbox']/@href
```